# translatetransform and zindex

Tags: silverlight-4.0, z-index

I have a silverlight project that uses translate and scale transforms in the form of a pan/zoom canvas. I put two columns around my pan/zoom canvas and one over the top of it. I set z-indexes on everything but my translate transform seems to run over the top of my outside columns. Is this normal behavior for the translate transform? Is there a workaround or anything I can do to "clip" the excess objects away from the screen until they are dragged back in?

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged my layout to allow for a fixed size canvas and then I used a clipping mask to hide the rest. It works for what I need for now.

```
 <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 800, 600"/>
            </Canvas.Clip>
```